# Using a Closure for infinite scrolling page?

Tags: javascript

When the scroll has reached the bottom of the page, I want to fetch more data and append those elements to the DOM.
So everytime the bottom of the page was hit, I'd fetch data from the server for a new page that increments...'http://myapi.com/page/1'

I was wondering if I can use a closure to encapsulate that incrementing variable.

```
const dataAction = function () {
     let i = 0;
     return function() {
          fetch('http://myapi.com/page/' + i)
          .then(() => {
             i += 1;
             // do something;
          }
     }
}
```

then I can instantiate it with `let fetchDataFunc = dataAction()`
and then anytime the scroll bottom is reach, I can run `fetchDataFunc()`.
Would the be the correct usage of closures?

Comment: Sure, why not ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance is that the intended use? Just wanted to make sure I was using them correctly.  I had a hard time figuring out a good use for a closure naturally and that idea just came to me

Comment: Yes perfect use case, that allows to make a "stateful" function that does not expose its internal state

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks like it would work just fine.